# Which of the following sentences is the correct one?

Tags: grammaticality, non-native-english

Which's the correct form of writing the following sentence?

1. "Whose fault is it when you're someone's broken promise?"
   "The person who made it or the person about whom it was made?"
2. "Whose fault is it to be someone's broken promise?"
   "The person who made it or the person about whom it was made?"

What I mean by the context is to wonder who's to blame when a person is a broken promise (the object of the promise) made by someone else. For instance, your best friend made a promise using you as the main reason of it but you acted in a way where you broke that promise (even though you never wanted to be involved in any of that).

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What do you mean by "using you as the main reason of it"? Your friend has promised a third party that *you* would *do* something for them? Your friend has promised to do something for a third party but something you've done has made it impossible for your friend to keep the promise?

Comment: Here's the truth... my mom spent years praying to have a child, and when she finally got it (me), she promised God she'd raise me to the point where she'd "return" me back to Him (The Lord gave, The Lord shall have it back someday). But considering the way I've been living my life, there is no guarantee she'll follow through with that promise. Therefore, this is what I mean by "being someone's broken promise".

Comment: Okay, but my question is regarding grammar. Which of the sentences is correct?

Comment: Are you asking about the proper way to phrase the question? If so, and ignoring the lack of clarity in "when you're someone's broken promise":    *Whose fault is it when you're someone's broken promise, the person who made it or the person about whom it was made?*   Or "Can a person be rightly accused of breaking a promise they themselves did not make?"

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!

Comment: As far as grammar goes, they're both acceptable.

Comment: Thank you, Barmar!

Comment: The second sentence is a bit more awkward.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, the idea of a promise made by Smith that someone else, say Jones, will do is a figurative kind of use.  I say 'strictly' because the dictionaries I have consulted do not mention it.  For example, the Cambridge English dictionary defines the verb as follows.

> to tell someone that **you** will certainly do something.

So you cannot make a promise that someone else will do something. The most that can be said is that that person has told you that they they will do it.

Merriam Webster gives a wider set of definitions.  In addition to the main definition, similar to that of CED, it gives a more nuanced usage:

> a legally binding declaration that gives the person to whom it is made a right to expect or to claim the performance or forbearance of a specified act

This definition allows for a broader understanding, more applicable to political or business/company context in which some leader or manager makes promises that have to be carried out by others.

However, in neither case, so far as I am aware, can it be said literally that those others that were supposed to carry out the 'promise' are themselves the 'broken promises'. It is the promise itself that is broken.

Similarly, the further removed the context becomes from actions both to be carried out by the promiser and within the direct power of the promiser to bring them about, as opposed to relying on the actions of others or on beliefs of the promiser about the probable future actions of others, the less of a strict promise the utterance is.

That cannot change the fact that in the development of political manifestos and company advertising this figurative use of the word promise is more and more common. For example, it has become common for UK political parties to make some number (generally five or six) memorable 'headline' promises in their election.  In such a context, it would make sense to say that, say that 'average hospital waiting time halved in two years' is a 'broken promise' if by that time no such improvement has taken place.  It would similarly be a legitimate rhetorical move to say on that basis that "the NHS is a broken promise."  It makes the broken promise claim more vivid.  There is a rhetorical/literary term for this:  *transferred epithet*.  The epithet, *broken promise* is transferred from the promise itself to the subject of the promise, namely the NHS.

So, in the example concerned in the question, the description 'broken promise', applied to the person promised, is a rhetorical/literary 'transferred epithet'.  A promises to B that C will do something (marry him/her or whatever it may be). B goes back to A in distress and tells A bitterly that "C is you broken promise".  That is, B's distress at being rejected is a breach of the promise made by A and so is A's fault.

Now, if A knew perfectly well that C was not in love with B because she was actually in a secret relationship with him (A), then the promise was made in bad faith and a deliberately broken assurance. It is still A's fault in raising false hopes in B.  So would it be if A had neither a basis for making the promise nor any such relationship with C but just made the promise to stop B from annoyingly agonising: then A would still be at least partially responsible B's disappointment, and,in effect, the promise would have been made in bad faith. B's disappointment was in part at least A's fault.

However, we should do well to stick with the classic definition of making a promise. That in the sense under it can only express a commitment to carry out some action.